# puppeteer runs locally but not in Git Pipeline

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I wrote a pipeline which shoul run the script "npm run test".
Locally npm run test is working just fine.
This is part of my Pipeline:

```
test:
  tags:
    - docker
    - migros
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install node@16.13.0
    - npm run test
```

But when I push my Code to gitlab the pipeline fails with this errormessage:

```
Setup Puppeteer
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/builds/devops-open-source/net.migros.news-hub.reactfrontend/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-818858/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
    at onClose (/builds/devops-open-source/net.migros.news-hub.reactfrontend/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/builds/devops-open-source/net.migros.news-hub.reactfrontend/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:183:68)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at Interface.close (node:readline:586:8)
    at Socket.onend (node:readline:277:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm run testing
    at makeError (/builds/devops-open-source/net.migros.news-hub.reactfrontend/node_modules/start-server-and-test/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (/builds/devops-open-source/net.migros.news-hub.reactfrontend/node_modules/start-server-and-test/node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm run testing',
  command: 'npm run testing',
  escapedCommand: '"npm run testing"',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! net.migros.news-hub.frontend@0.1.0 test: `start-server-and-test develop http://localhost:8000 testing`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the net.migros.news-hub.frontend@0.1.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-17T08_20_03_043Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` you probably need to install these libraries in your pipeline. Maybe one easy way is to install chrome/chromium using your package manager, which should include all the requirements needed for puppeteer to run chromium.

Answer (score -1):

> Setup Puppeteer
> Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
> /builds/devops-open-source/net.migros.news-hub.reactfrontend/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-818858/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Your runner/image does not have libraries needed to run chromium/chrome. You need to install system dependencies in your runner/image or job for this to work. e.g. `apt install -y chromium-browser` or `apt install -y google-chrome` (with repos added) for ubuntu/debian based systems.